# How two motors connected in series can be used as dynamo?

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits

I want to use two motors as dynamo and connect them in series for a better voltage. Is it possible anyhow to connect the motors in series by using diode or other parts so that when one motor is being used as dynamo,it won't power the other one?

Comment: Why not have a single shaft rotating both dynamos?

Comment: So you're going to use a drive chain or something similar to attach the motors? Or what @Farcher said?

Comment: It depends on the geometry of the motors and the type of motors.